# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for gcloud beta code dev?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to [install](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local) cloud beta code dev to develop docker containers locally to use on cloud run

```
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container] Traceback (most recent call last):
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]   File "./main.py", line 5, in <module>
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]     import storage_utils
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]   File "/storage_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]     client = storage.Client()
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 165, in __init__
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]     _http=_http,
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py", line 320, in __init__
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]     _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project, credentials=credentials)
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py", line 268, in __init__
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]     project = self._determine_default(project)
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py", line 287, in _determine_default
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]     return _determine_default_project(project)
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers/__init__.py", line 152, in _determine_default_project
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]     _, project = google.auth.default()
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 579, in default
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container]     raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
[stashstock-to-cloud-storage-container] google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

I have previously run

```
> gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <path-to-key-file>
Activated service account credentials for: [cloud-functions-service-key@greendata-dbt.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

and when I echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS I see the file path.

Also I can

```
> echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
<path-to-my-key>.json
```

so it appears the environment variable is set. Should cloud beta code dev be working right now? Or do I have to set these credentials somehow else?

Comment: Are you running the `gcloud beta code dev` command with the `--application-default-credential` or the `--service-account` flag? Which one?

Comment: @JackWotherspoon do I have to use either? I just want to set it up (see the example here) https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/code

Comment: If you check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local#gcloud-cli)  at the bottom in the `Using Credentials` section, it states that if your running `gcloud beta code dev`and attempting to access Google Cloud services (which it seems you are since I see `storage.Client()`) that you need to use one of the flags. I would attempt to use one of the flags and let me know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: using the --service-account flag does seem to work. However it seems to create an additional service key for me. Im not sure why it doesn't want to use the existing one

Comment: @BigBoy1337: Can you confirm that what Jack Wotherspoon provided fixed your issue?, please.

Comment: @AndresFiescoCasasola I cannot say that the issue is fixed since I am still unable to run this command without error. However, the issue is now different than what I posted in this question so Im not sure what to do with it. For my current issue, I created a issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231355531